# Indian citizen planning to marry a Polish citizen

Tags: working-visas, marriage, indian-citizens, poland, dependent-visa

I'm an Indian citizen and I'm planning to marry my Polish girlfriend. After the marriage, we are considering the option of moving to Poland. I wanted to know if I can move to Poland right away after the marriage and how long it will be before I can work in Poland.

Do I still need to get a work permit to work in Poland if I'm married to a Polish national or can I start working right away? Additionally, if I do need a work permit, how long does that take?

Comment: I have the same question, please tell me if it worked out for you If yes then how and If not then why? I live in India and my Polish girlfriend will soon be visiting me and we are planning to get married here in India and move together toPoland. please bro, I'm not sure If I will ever visit this website again and I desperately need this answer. Please wrote me on prashantpareek16@outlook.com

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends whether you have been living in another EU country together or not before trying to settle in Poland. If you have, then [EU laws](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/worker-pensioner/non-eu-family-members/index_en.htm) will apply, which provide you with the same coverage as any other EU member, including employment. EU laws will also apply if you *both* plan on moving to a different EU country to live and work there.

If not, then Polish national laws will apply to you (until you have moved together to a different EU country). Fortunately Polish laws are also [quite lenient](http://www.foreignersinpoland.com/work/work-permit-in-poland.html), as you won't need a work permit if "you are the spouse or a former spouse of a Polish citizen, provided that they have a residence permit for Polish territory".

Note that your marriage needs to be recognized by Polish Immigration and they might also [do some checks](http://www.globaldetentionproject.org/fileadmin/docs/Poland_Aliens_Act.pdf) (Act 55, Section 1) to determine whether your marriage was "not been concluded for the purpose of abuse by an alien the provisions on granting a residence permit for a fixed period on the territory of the Republic of Poland".

Comment: Applying for a regular local visa/permit under local law is always possible. EU law could also apply but that's mostly relevant in countries with unusually restrictive visa regimes for family relatives like the UK and the Netherlands and it does not supersede local law in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate it. From what I understand, if my girlfriend and I get married according to the requirements stated by the polish government then I can apply for the residence permit for fixed period right away on the basis of being married to a Polish citizen who is currently residing in Poland. I believe the permit takes couple months (background checks) to process after which I can move to Poland. Once this is done, I do not require a work permit to work in Poland and can start working as soon as I find a job. Is that correct? Thanks.